# How to make a Snackbar not overlaps the android navigation control

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar

If I use the Snackbar with a FloatingActionButton the snacks Works fine because the FAB is inside of a CoordinatorLayout layout, but what I want is to make the Snackbar as a action and not be activated by a FAB, I tried to make the Activity as CoordinatorLayout but stil doesnt't Works!

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

This is how the Snackabr reacts inside of a FAB :

[image]

And how reacts outside of FAB :

[image]

This is how I do outside of FAB!

```
Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "Ative o GPS para usar nossos serviços", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });
        bar.show();
```

Comment: Could you explain more, there is no difference between images and can't get what do you want exactly.
Thanks!

Comment: @KhaledQasem sorry, I had uploaded the image twice!

Comment: I've answered the question could you try it please? @Nathiel Paulino

Comment: Yeah I did, bit one questiom, the "content" would be what ?

Comment: Did it work well ?

Comment: I got a error of the activity.findViewById, what is the content ? is the activity ?

Comment: The `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()` call in your second snippet is causing that. Why don't you just pass it a `View` like in the first one? It can be any `View` that's within the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: No this is just to indicate to your activity so you can parse your activity -in other words if you are in activity you can call findViewById with activity - .
So you just need to parse your activity or context to call it

Comment: @NathielPaulino could you call it directly without activity?

Comment: Look, I was calling from a view because it was inside of a FAB, but now  its outside, If i try to get the activity, the snack goes over the navigation control, what view should I pass ? Just create a view on my activity ?

Comment: You can pass any `View` that's inside the `CoordinatorLayout`; e.g., the FAB.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try to create it with  "activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)"

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
 "Replace with your own action",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Comment: Altought Nathiel didn't mark the answer as correct, the solution worked for me. This puts the snackbar at the bottom-most part of the screen, where the screen is only where there's content, instead of the whole smartphone screen.

Comment: Also worked for me, although FWIW I don't have a FAB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a "child of a suitable view" for a `Snackbar` to behave nicely. A suitable view is one that is either a `CoordinatorLayout`, a `FrameLayout` or `android.R.id.content`.

See `com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar#findSuitableParent` which defines this, and also `Snackbar.make` function's Javadoc explains it.

Be careful passing in `android.R.id.content`, because it'll result in `Snackbar` overlapping FAB:
[image]

If the UI contains a FAB, it's best to always pass that or its `CoordinatorLayout`, so the `Snackbar` can push the FAB up.